# ¿Por qué no me cambia de color el jTextField? Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un formulario en el cual relleno los datos, los cuales los obtengo de una consulta `SQL` y los vuelco en los correspondientes `jTextField`.
Quiero que si el valor de v[3] es 1, el fondo del jTextField se ponga color verde, y si es 0, el fondo del jTextField se ponga color rojo.

¿Qué error tengo debido a que sólo aparece un color, el inicial, y al cambiar de bastidor no actualiza el campo `textfield_disponible`?

**Código:**

```
private void jComboBox_bastidorItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                    
        //Recogemos en la variable "bastidor" el valor seleccionado en el combobox con el método "getSelectedItem()".
        String bastidor = (String) jComboBox_bastidor.getSelectedItem();
        //Guardamos en un objecto "v" los datos del bastidor gracias a la función "Conexiones.datos_de_un_bastidor_alquiler(bastidor);".
        Object[] v = Conexiones.datos_de_un_bastidor_alquiler(bastidor);
        //Otorgamos a los campos jTextField los valores recogidos en el "Object[] v".
        textfield_marca.setText(String.valueOf(v[0]));
        textfield_marca.setEditable(false);
        textfield_modelo.setText(String.valueOf(v[1]));
        textfield_modelo.setEditable(false);
        textfield_matricula.setText(String.valueOf(v[2]));
        textfield_matricula.setEditable(false);
        textfield_disponible.setText(String.valueOf(v[3]));
        textfield_disponible.setEditable(false);
        String texto = String.valueOf(v[3]);

        if(texto == "1")
            textfield_disponible.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        else
            textfield_disponible.setBackground(Color.RED);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues tu error se encuentra en la condición del `if` ya que para compara cadenas debes usar el `equals`, tu código debería ser algo como esto:

```
textfield_disponible.setText(String.valueOf(v[3]));
textfield_disponible.setEditable(false);
String texto = String.valueOf(v[3]);
if(texto.equals("1"))
    textfield_disponible.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
else
    textfield_disponible.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Perfecto Efren.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tu color ha de ser en Mayusculas, ya que es una constante (y estática, por eso no hace falta instanciar la clase `Color`).

```
textfield_disponible.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: Cierto, lo que ocurre que al cambiar el valor de un campo combobox, el valor varía pero no varía el color, me sale siempre el inicial.

Answer (score -1):

2 factores:
 1- puede que estés omitiendo la clase que da los colores a esos objetos: `import java.awt.*;`

2- estas escribiendo capitalizado los colores:
`setbackground(color.Green)` en lugar de `setbackground(color.green)` también la podrías escribir `setbackground(color.GREEN)`